# how can I enable IOS6 tethering without jailbreaking my Sprint iphone 4s phone?

Tags: ios, tethering

I know that you can enable tethering for an IOS6 iphone by jail breaking it and then installing additional tethering software but how can I enable IOS6 thetering without jailbreaking my Sprint iphone 4s phone?
I am aware that you can pay extra to get the "Mobile Share Plan" but I am not interested in paying extra for this service since I am already paying for unlimited data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the "Mobile Share Plan" enabled first from your phone service provider. To see if you have it, find `Personal Hotspot`. It should be in `Settings -> General -> Network -> Cellular Data Network`. Please see [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4517) for more information.

Like I said, if you do not see the option for Personal Hotspot, confirm with your carrier that this feature is supported and your wireless plan is configured for Personal Hotspot.

Comment: I am aware that you can pay extra to get the "Mobile Share Plan" but I am not interested in paying extra for this service since I am already paying for unlimited data.  I will add this to the question.